# Function keeps returning to while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

My problem: A card generator which keeps calling my recursive function.

Here are my two functions

```
public static string GenerateHoleCards()
{
    Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    string cardOne = ranks[rnd.Next(0, 12)];
    string suitCardone = suits[rnd.Next(0, 3)];
    string cardTwo = ranks[rnd.Next(0, 12)];
    string suitCardtwo = suits[rnd.Next(0, 3)];

    while (!CheckForDealtHoleCards(cardOne + suitCardone, cardTwo + suitCardtwo))
    {
        GenerateHoleCards();
    }

    return cardOne + suitCardone + cardTwo + suitCardtwo;  
}

private static bool CheckForDealtHoleCards(string holeCard1, string holeCard2) 
{
    if (holeCard1 == holeCard2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (dealtHolecards.Contains(holeCard1) || dealtHolecards.Contains(holeCard2)) 
    {
        return false;
    }       

    dealtHolecards.Add(holeCard1);
    dealtHolecards.Add(holeCard2);

    return true;
}
```

When `GenerateHoleCards` returns my string it jumps back to my while calling my function. 
I probably have a thinking error here, so where is it guys?

Comment: Ok, you have an obvious recursive function -- however, what is it you are TRYING to do... Try and explain the purpose of this program, not just the code.  Fixing a recursion problem is one thing, trying to get something done in a more effective way is another.

Comment: First generate cards , second check whether the generated cards already exist ( by adding them to a list). third generate new cards if cards exist. Of course I'm very much open to a better solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a recusion. Your method calls itself. After that call returns, you are in the method that called it, which is the same method.

If you look at the depth of the call stack, you can see how many times the method has called itself. After the `return` statement, that depth decreases by one.

Note that in the statement `GenerateHoleCards();`, you do not pick up the return value from the call.

---

Maybe you want something like this instead of recursion:

```
public static string GenerateHoleCards()
{
    // rnd should be declared elsewhere, the seed should be sane

    string cardOne, suitCardone, cardTwo, suitCardtwo;
    do
    {
        cardOne = ranks[rnd.Next(0, 12)];
        suitCardone = suits[rnd.Next(0, 3)];
        cardTwo = ranks[rnd.Next(0, 12)];
        suitCardtwo = suits[rnd.Next(0, 3)];
    } while (!CheckForDealtHoleCards(cardOne + suitCardone, cardTwo + suitCardtwo));

    return cardOne + suitCardone + cardTwo + suitCardtwo;  
}
```

Comment: Of course , there is my thinking error! thanks! I checked the callstack and drew it out on paper. Stupid.

Comment: Ooh and I also refactored the seed suggestion thanks for that too.